# Tutorials/Learning Resources for Implementing a Script Interpreter (e.g. Python, Lua) in C#

Tags: c#, python, lua

I'm looking for a complete tutorial / learning resource, from which I can learn how to implement a script parser in  C#.

My intention is to implement such a system within a game engine to promote the creation of user generated content.

Edit: This is more as a learning exercise than anything else.

Comment: why don't use one already done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just integrate an existing script parser (e.g.: [integrating Lua into C#](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/using-lua-with-c-r2275))?